# How to save the results obtained with TwitterPager into a JSON file?

Tags: json, twitterapi-python

I am exploring a code example given by geduldig for his module TwitterPager. The code functions perfectly well, but for some reason and after many different attempts at possible solutions, I am unable to save the outcome into a JSON file.

This is the code example I am exploring, with slight modifications:

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
from TwitterAPI import TwitterPager
import json

consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'
access_token = 'xxx'
access_secret = 'xxx'

api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,  access_secret)

r = TwitterPager(api, 'search/tweets', {'q':'pizza', 'count':100})
for item in r.get_iterator():
    if 'text' in item:       
        # print (item['text'])
        print (item)
    elif 'message' in item and item['code'] == 88:
        print ('SUSPEND, RATE LIMIT EXCEEDED: %s\n' % item['message'])
        break
```

## Then I added the following piece of code:

```
with open('pizza.json', 'a') as fp:
    json.dump(item, fp)
```

The output I get yields, in fact, the whole JSON string from Twitter, not just the text, as requested. But the last piece of code cannot save the outcome into a JSON file. I think it might have perhaps something to do with the "for loop", but I cannot wrap my head around it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `item` is the entire [tweet object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object), not just the text. Try this:

```
json.dump(item['text'], fp)
```

Comment: Thank you, Jonas, for your kind answer! The problem arose because I tried to save the json file outside the function (that is, I hadn't indented the json code correctly). I apologize for the silly mistake! In any case, for the purpose of my research, I am using the TwitterPager module to capture not just the text, but the whole information contained in the tweet. In this sense, the module functions very well too.